# Using a local Repository in Maven for ElasticSearch

Tags: java, git, maven, elasticsearch, lucene

When I am using Elastic Search, my module compiles and runs properly.
In my **pom.xml**, I have included the following dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But I needed to do some changes(implement a timer in one of the methods of ES), so I forked the code, made a jar and saved it in my local repository:-

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/Mike/Desktop/MyElastic/elasticsearch/target/elasticsearch-1.4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=org.elasticsearch -DartifactId=elasticsearch -Dversion=1.4.6-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Now I am trying to use this locally saved repository instead of the remote repository.
So I made the following changes to my **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But now when I compile my module, some strange error is being thrown :-

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/lucene/util/Version    at
>   org.elasticsearch.Version.(Version.java:44)   at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.(InternalNode.java:137)
>     at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)   at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:166)     at
>   mike.practice.ES.PracticeES3.(PracticeES3.java:55)  at
>   mike.practice.ES.PracticeES3.main(PracticeES3.java:177)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.lucene.util.Version    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 11 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What could have been the possible error? Is it that my local repository is not being properly mapped. Or probably some issue with the version ?( was using 1.4.5 earlier but when I forked and reverted to 1.4, automatically 1.4.6 was selected)

It would be really helpful if somebody could help me find out what the real issue is and how to correct it.

Comment: Please check the `lucene` jars and its versions int the `classpath`

Comment: @sarohan Thanks for replying. I Checked up the error and found that I need to include following dependencies:-

org.slf4j-slf4j-api-1.7.5

org.slf4j-slf4j-api-1.6.4

Comment: No  some lucene error, I don't know why  but I had to add lucene seperately,

lucene-4.10.4 in dependency ,

Now it's saying,

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/hunspell/Dictionary`

Comment: I feel I am doing something wrong, one error is leading to another one. While using the remote repository , everything was working fine.

Comment: Please ensure that you have added all the elasticsearch dependency jars in your class path. I hope you missed some `lucene` jars or its  dependencies.

**Note:** Please refer the jars in `%ES_HOME%/lib` folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79290/discussion-between-sarohan-and-mike3162114).

Comment: to ease you life I would also add the pom file https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.4/pom.xml beside the jar - so maven knows what dependencies are also required. You can use the same maven command (just change the type) for the pom file as well. Otherwise that might end up in adding jar by jar. Or clone the repository and do a mvn install for that branch?